# Can I embedded HTML tags in an HREF's TITLE? (I need some sort of line break)

Tags: html

It seems not,as they are showing up as cleartext.

I am trying to format a rather large tootlip by inserting `<p>` and `<br>`, but, as I say, Chrome treats them as text.

What am I allowed to put into such a tooltip? Anything other than a single string?

Since `\n` seems to be ignored, is there any way to get a line break into such a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add symbol for a new line: `&#013;` (\r) or `&#010;` (\n) to your title.

```html
<a href="" title="first row&#013;second row&#010;third row">test</a>
```

Another option is to find some JavaScript tooltip library.

Answer (score 1):

If you feed them actual line breaks, they will work.

```html
<span title="Two
Liner">Hover here</span>
```

However, if you need more complex HTML inside, I'd suggest [qTip](http://qtip2.com/) or [Bootstrap's tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)